# Ayuda, mi idea es presionar sobre una fila el archivo solicitud y que eso me habra o direccione cargandose el archivo

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

```
function cargaPagina(pagina)
{
  var desde = pagina * itemsPorPagina;

  $.ajax({
    data:{"param1":"dame","limit":itemsPorPagina,"offset":desde},
    type:"GET",
    dataType:"json",
    url:"Conexion_Mostrar_Solicitud_Pedido.php"
  }).done(function(data,textStatus,jqXHR){

    var lista = data.lista;

    $("#miTabla").html("");

    $.each(lista, function(ind, elem){

      $("<tr>"+

        "<td>"+elem.id_solicitud_pedido+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+elem.nombre_contacto_empresa+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+elem.empresa_solicitud_pedido+"</td>"+
        "<td>"+elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido + "</td>"+
        "<td>"+elem.fecha_solicitud_pedido+"</td>"+
        "</tr>").appendTo($("#miTabla"));


    });     


  }).fail(function(jqXHR,textStatus,textError){
    alert("Error al realizar la peticion dame".textError);

  });
```

Comment: Me da la impresión que le falta detallar más que desea lograr para que le puedan orientar mejor al respecto.

Comment: @RobertoLeónOramas lo que deseo, es que en tabla ahi columna con nombre de archivos, lo que deseo es que al presionar sobre esa columna me pueda abrir en otra pantalla el pdf, no se si me lograste comprender. saludos

Comment: @Keane Puedes mejorar tu pregunta corrigiendo el título y agregando como encabezado el comentario de arriba? Esta pregunta puede ser útil para alguien mas, pero no si no describe correctamente el problema que tiene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Saludos**

Para que eso ocurra depende como este configurado el PlugIns de Acrobat para [Mostrar PDF en un navegador](https://helpx.adobe.com/es/acrobat/using/display-pdf-in-browser.html); asumiendo que esta bien (esto depende del lado del cliente); lo único que tienes que hacer es abrir una ventna; una forma fácil es usando el tag `<a></a>` a continuación una sugerencia:

```
<a href="http://misitio/algunaruta/MiPDF.pdf" target="_blank">
Click para abrir pdf
</a>
```

Como lo quieres dentro de una columna de tu tabla prueba una de las siguientes para darte idea y optar por la que prefieras:

```
<a href="http://misitio/algunaruta/MiPDF.pdf" 
         target="_blank" style="width:100%; height:auto;">
Click para abrir pdf
</a>
```

ó

```
<a href="http://misitio/algunaruta/MiPDF.pdf" target="_blank">
<div style="width:100%; height:auto;">
Click para abrir pdf
</div>
</a>
```

> Para el height prueba con `100%` y `auto` cual funcione; la intención es que se extienda a lo alto y ancho del `td` donde lo coloques.

Lo que puse como `http://misitio/algunaruta/MiPDF.pdf` es directo si el PDF existe; es decir, pero puede ser un ink donde crees el PDF al vuelo; claro sustituyendo como debe ser.

Con `target="_blank"` se indica que abra en ventana nueva; [otros valores para target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) según requieras.

> La parte que permite se abra con el navegador web en otra ventana la
>   verdad no la he comprendido bien; por ejemplo comunmente primero
>   tienes que tener instalado (el visitante) al menos el Adobe Acrobat
>   Reader (y con ello el PlugIns) sin embargo tengo Chrome y no he
>   instalado programa similar o el Plugins y lo abre el Chrome, en fin.

Espero te sea de utilidad u orientación.

> **EDITADO**

En consideración que lo pondrás en `"<td>"+elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido + "</td>"`; sería algo como:

```
"<td> <a href=\"http://misitio/algunaruta/"+elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido + "\" target="_blank">
    <div style=\"width:100%; height:auto;\">
    Click para abrir pdf
    </div>
    </a></td>"
```

como desconozco la ruta del archivo deje lo que te ejemplifique; así que tendras que colocar `http://misitio/algunaruta/` según corresponda  estoy asumiendo que `elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido` es el nombre archivo que se deberá abrir.

Comment: Leon Oramas, pero como coloco <a></a> en esa linea de codigo "<td>"+elem.archivo_solicitud_pedido + "</td>"+, porque es ahi donde me va a mostrar en la tabla todo los datos que esten en la bbdd

Comment: Gracias Roberto Leon Oramas, me sirvió mucho tu respuesta, pude comprender algunas cosas y gracias por comentar, se agradece mucho

Comment: @Keane me falto en **target="_blank"** debe ser **target=\"_blank\"** el **\"** es por que usas como inicio de cadena **"** y por consiguiente debe ser el mismo para cierre; con **\"** se "escapa" **"** a fin de evitar cuando lo encuentre sin l\** lo tome como inicio o fin de otra cadena.